# html5 hero video will not centre when the viewport is moved in from the right

Tags: html, video

I am in the process of creating a website and want a video background that scrolls. This is what I have so far: [www.sawvisuals.com/video1.html](http://www.sawvisuals.com/video1.html)

The website is/will be responsive and I only intend to have the video on the desktop version. I will have a static image for tablets and phones.

My problem is that when the viewport is moved in from the right the video does not stay centred. I really want it to stay centred at all time, any help would be great.

All my code so far is as follows:

**HTML**

```
<div class="gridContainer">


<div id="wraper">

<video autoplay loop muted poster="images/bg-image.jpg" class="bgvideo"         
id="bgvideo">
<source src="videos/clouds.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="videos/clouds.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>

</div>

<div class="spacer">

<div class="desktop-header">
<div class="desktop-logo">LOGO HERE</div>
<div class="desktop-links">Link1 Link2 Link3 Link4 Link5</div>
</div>


</div>

<div class="info">
      <h6> CREATIVE SOLUTIONS FOR PRINT, <br>WEB & VISUALISATION </h6>
</div>

<div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </div>


</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.gridContainer {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1920px;
    padding-left: 0%;
    padding-right: 0%;
    margin: auto;
}
.bgvideo {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: -9999;
}
.spacer {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}
.text {
    width: 90%;
    padding-left: 5%;
    padding-right: 5%;
    padding-top: 200px;
    padding-bottom: 200px;
    background-color: #9FF;
}
.info {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    width: 90%;
    font-size: 36px;
    color: #fff;
    -ms-transform: translate(0,-50%); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: translate(0,-50%); /* Safari */
    transform: translate(0,-50%);
}
.desktop-header {
    display: table;
    width: 90%;
    padding-left: 5%;
    padding-right: 5%;
    padding-top: 4%;
    background-color: #FFF;
}
.desktop-logo {
    float: left;
    width: 12%;
}
.desktop-links {
    width: 88%;
    float: left;
    clear: none;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Any help in centering this video is going to be massively appreciate.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're setting `width:auto` and `height:auto` instead of setting both to 100%?

Comment: When I change the width and height from auto to 100% the videos placement is off if I remember correctly. It has been a while since a edited that information as I have just been trying to centre the video.

Answer (score 0):

try using this around the divisions of the video bg you want. it will center it

```html
<center>
  <div>
    <!--Put your code here of the item you want to center-->
    </div>
  </center>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion I will try it as soon as possible! Will adding the <centre> Tag make the video overflow from both sides equally?

Comment: Hey, just tried adding the <center> tags around the video code but it doesn't allow the video to overflow off both side of the screen. I just cannot get it to centre.

Comment: What do you mean by you cannot get the video to overflow both sides of the screen?

Comment: Maybe you can make a division

Comment: by  using <div> </Div> tags like so

Comment: <div align="center"> Video Goes here </div> you may have to even make a float height in the script like so: put in head files <script type="text/javascript"> put you functions here and make an id for the functions </script> then put this in the div tags using the id you used to make it not mine, <div ID="PUT THE ID HERE"> video inside</div> the id tag may not be correct i don't use them often sorry if it isn't just go to w3Schools.com and look up html div id tags in the search hope this helped also could you uproot my video so I can get more rep and leave my answer as correct?

Comment: Hey Noah, Thanks for the suggestion I will try it asap.